# React.js: React dropdown does not hold data

Tags: reactjs

I would like to ask why does my dropdown can't hold the value after selecting.

ClientMaintenancePage.js

```
/* Dropdown */
const optionsBrstn = [
   'BIC', 'BRSTN', 'Bank Name'
];

const defaultOption = options[0];

<form className="form-horizontal form-group">
      <Dropdown options={optionsBrstn} onSelect={_onSelect} value={defaultOption} placeholder="Select an option" />
      <div className="text-right mt-2">
            <MDBBtn color="indigo" type="button" onClick={() => {}}>Add</MDBBtn>
            <MDBBtn color="indigo" type="button" onClick={() => {}}>Delete</MDBBtn>
            <MDBBtn color="indigo" type="button" onClick={() => {}}>Save</MDBBtn>
      </div>
</form>
```

It was originally this._onSelect, however I am not using a class component that's why I cannot use the this keyword.

May I know what approach can I use for this using React hooks.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `optionsBrstn`. I can not see `options` variable or state.

```
const defaultOption = optionsBrstn[0]
```

One more thing, `defaultOption` is  const so if you change the selected option on change, it will not reflect in your select. It should be kept in a state.

Comment: I have another question though, what should I put in the onSelect property?

Comment: Ofcourse, It depends what you want to do in onSelect.